# How to keep labels from moving

Tags: qgis

I'm making a complex map with many labels (with QGIS 3.4.11). I manually arrange them for readability, attractiveness, etc.. However, I find that when I zoom in or out, or pan the view, their positions change. I don't want that. I want all of them to look the same (in the same positions), regardless of the current view. Under "Rendering" I do not have "Scale dependent visibility" checked; nor "Pixel sized-based visibility". I have checked "Show all labels..." Do I need a certain setting under "Data defined"?

Comment: Please, be more specific about the steps taken. Include screenshots of each window, tab, section or option to which you are referring. Include a GeoPackage file with the project and one data sample layer if needed. As the question is written, it is not possible for me to understand the steps taken or what is being asked.

Comment: did you specify a specific x,y location for the label? if so how? did you specify "where" in relation to the point the label should be drawn?

Comment: I have found that the "shifting labels" problem occurs only with labels that have not been manually moved. So a solution to this problem is to simply tweak the position of each label. Then they stay put in relation to their surroundings, regardless of how one zooms in/out or pans the view.